# FFmpeg making video from images placed in different folders

Tags: ffmpeg

I am making video from images in FFmpeg. I want to know if I can make video from images placed in different folders. Like first image is placed in folder1 and other in folder2 can I use both images in folder1 and folder2 to make a single video having both images in any order. Just want to know can I use images from two different folders to make a single video. if yes. Than how can i do that?

Comment: Read your question, do you really thing that someone can understand what you are doing and what you expect as a resulting video... Does folder name follow a logic(show a kind of tree to explain) and what kind of video do you want ... all the image of folder1, and after all the image of folder2, etc... ?

Comment: @alexbuisson did you get it now???

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes it's possible, you can specify several input on the command (-i) but the more easy in your case as the order doesn't count, is to use the 'concat' ' filter

https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20concatenate%20(join,%20merge)%20media%20files

it will create a video with all images of folder1 and after all folder2, etc... 
The concat filter come with 2 methods:

```
ffmpeg -i concat:file1|file2 etc ....
```

and

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i list etc...
```

for image sequence it look like only the 2nd method work.
so first create a file to describe your content (run `touch file` and edit it with `nano file`) and use the following syntax to specify where your file are and which is their naming syntax:

```
file './folder1/im%03d.jpg'
file './folder2/im%03d.jpg'
```

save the file (under `nano` it will be with `CTRL+X`)
and now run the following command:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i list out.mp4
```

ffmpeg will use your `file` as input and push sequentially all your image in the encoding process

Comment: cancat runs on linux. Is there a solution for this for windows command prompt as I am using windows.

Comment: hum, the "concat" demuxer is part of ffmpeg, so if you use the same ffmpeg version on Linux & windows it MUST work .... and if talked about the "cat" command it also exist under windows if you setup some additional package like Cygwin !

Comment: I have tried the concat command in linux but it is giving an error "At least one output file must be specified". My command is:                                                                                                                                  ffmpeg -r 1 -f image2 -i concat:/home/phedra/imgs/image/img%03d.png'|'/home/phedra/imgs/images/img%03d.png -i /home/phedra/imgs/image/audio.mp3 -acodec copy -r 20 /home/phedra/imgs/video/video4.mpg

Comment: After some test I agree the 1st concat method file but the 2nd method using a file to list the content work (tested on ubuntu/ffmpeg 2.0.1)! See my edit

Comment: Added more details, on how create the file but basically it's just a text file to describe where your sequence are and their respective naming convention (im000.jpg, im001.jpg are name using the im%03d.jpg format)

Comment: Note that this method is fully describe in the link i mentionned !